# Class "simpleModule" not found in omnetpp

Tags: networking, omnet++

I am writing my own simple modules in omnet++.

Inside the omnet IDE, I have created three simple modules.

After that I have created a "network" using those modules.

It is building successfully, but whenever I try to simulate it it shows

> Error in module (cModule) NetworkTopologyOnly (id=1) during network
>   setup: Class "mySimplemodule2" not found -- perhaps its code was not
>   linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in
>   the case of modules and channels, with
>   Define_Module()/Define_Channel().

What should I do to successfully simulate using my own simple modules?

Comment: Have you built your project?

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory if you keep in mind that an OMNeT++ simulation is the OMNeT++ kernel linked (static or dynamic, just like any binary) with simulation model libraries. Each library will register all its models with the OMNeT++ kernel (this is what the macros mentioned in the error message do). This is what the error message is saying: the factory doesn't know about the model you are trying to instantiate - and it's laying out possible reasons why.

Comment: @JerzyD. Yes, it is building successfully. But while building a network topology and simulating it, it some simple modules were loaded but this simple module is causing the problem.

Comment: @ChristophSommer : yes but I have used Define_Module(simpleModuleName) in my .cc file. But Why am I still getting this error in the network topology ? However, it is building successfully

Comment: Is your own model library linked statically or dynamically? If the former: when launching the simulation, are you sure you are launching the binary you created?

Comment: How to know if I am linking statically or dynamically ? I have checked in the Run as config. It is using my build filename.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than class or module registering issues, this could also be caused when you have not implemented all its functions (if you have any non-virtual function prototype defined in your omnet++ class).

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the issue. I had defined one scheduler function in my simplemodule class but didn't implemented it.