# Run Time Error: perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class()/Define_Module()/Define_Channel()?

Tags: omnet++

I have already declared Define_Module(veins:: TraCIDateDissemination) and go through with various suggestions provided but getting this error again. Any suggestion is welcome. please help.

[How to register a new class (new application) in Omnet++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185836/how-to-register-a-new-class-new-application-in-omnet)
[Error in module during network setup:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985184/error-in-module-during-network-setup)
[Class "simpleModule" not found in omnetpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586147/class-simplemodule-not-found-in-omnetpp)
https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/

In manual I checked -

```
7.12.3 Class Registration
You should also use the Register_Class() macro to register the new class. It is used by the createOne() factory function, which can create any object given the class name as a string. createOne() is used by the Envir library to implement omnetpp.ini options such as rng-class="..." or scheduler-class="...". (see Chapter [17])
```

But not able to understand. pls help.

```
A runtime error occurred:

Class "TraCIDataDissemination" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel() -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) RSUExampleScenario.node[0] (id=13), at t=1s, event #2

Launch a debugger with the following command?

nemiver --attach=20070 &
```

OMNET.INI

```
##########################################################
#                      App Layer                         #
##########################################################
#*.node[*].applType = "TraCIDemo11p"
*.node[*].applType = "TraCIDataDissemination"
*.node[*].appl.headerLength = 80 bit
```

TraCIDataDissemination.h

```
namespace veins {

class TraCIDataDissemination : public DemoBaseApplLayer {
public:
{
//my code
}
}
```

TraCIDataDissemination.cc

```
#include "veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDataDissemination.h"
#include<math.h>
using namespace veins;

Define_Module(veins::TraCIDataDissemination);

//code
```

TraCIDataDissemination.ned

```
   package org.car2x.veins.modules.application.traci;
    import org.car2x.veins.modules.application.ieee80211p.DemoBaseApplLayer;
    
    simple TraCIDataDissemination extends DemoBaseApplLayer
    {
    
        @class(TraCIDataDissemination);
        @display("i=block/app2");
}
```

Please Help!!

Comment: You should check your namespaces - omnet++ seems to register class with namespace ("veins::TraCIDataDissemination" ?). @namespace() decoration in .ned file (or package.ned) tells what implicit namespace to use

Comment: https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-ref:resolving-cpp-class may help

Comment: @user2224044 no, the documentation is next to useless without a concrete example.